# ternary expression dependent on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have a data set similar to:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'Time':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'Value': [1,3,5,5,6,8,9,5,6,7]})
```

giving:

```
   Time  Value
0     1      1
1     2      3
2     3      5
3     4      5
4     5      6
5     6      8
6     7      9
7     8      4
8     9      6
9    10      7
```

What I want to do is set all values that are > 5 to equal 0 in "Values" but only when "Time" is > 5. End product would be:

```
   Time  Value
0     1      1
1     2      3
2     3      5
3     4      5
4     5      6
5     6      0
6     7      0
7     8      4
8     9      0
9    10      0
```

I have been using a code:

```
 DF.Value = [0 if x > 5 else x for x in DF.Value]
```

Which obviously changes *all* values to 0 if they are > 5. I have tried adding things to this code such as:

```
  DF.Value = [0 if x > 5 in DF.value and x > 5 in DF.Time else x for x in DF.Value]
```

But I can't seem to get the right combination of words/code to yield what I want. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it easy to use numpy.where in these situations:

```
import numpy as np
DF['Value'] = np.where((DF.Time > 5) & (DF.Value > 5),0,DF.Value)
```

*To add to this answer, in case there are more conditions that you want to satisfy you can add them to the above code like:

```
DF['Value'] = np.where((DF.Time > 500) & (DF.Value > 5) | (DF.Time > 5) & (DF.Value < 1),0,DF.Value)
```

Just add " | " and then write your next condition.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.